# Download button that send application to blackberry and asks everyone else to register?

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I would like to know your opinions on how to handle this.

I need to create a link or advertisement that offers a phone app to be downloaded.

I need that users who are viewing the page with their blackberry receive the download when they click the button but everyone else who would be viewing the page would get a form which asks that they insert a phone number to send the application to.

Has anyone else already tackled this or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [bit of code](http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/) to display different pages/div's to different browsers.

Comment: Looks great, thats what I would need, but unfortunately the site is sitting on an NT server so PHP isnt an option.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good place where to use `user-agent` sniffing.

Comment: Thanks, I dont know about this but I am looking it up now.